# Laravel-phpunit tests throw an error - There is no active transaction

Tags: laravel, pdo, phpunit

I'm using bitbucket pipeline to run and deploy my project. I have a couple of tests which are using the transaction to follow the atomicity principle, this is one of those transactions

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $child) {

    $this->authorize('accessRequestMoney', $child);

    $this->model->whereUserId($this->authenticated->id)->forceDelete();

    $data = [
                'amount'=> (float)$request->amount * 100,
                'day'=>$request->day,
                'enabled'=>$request->has('enabled') ? $request->enabled : true,
            ];

    $this->model->create(['user_id' => $this->authenticated->id, 'children_id' => $child->id] + $data);

}
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting the following error

```
PDOException: There is no active transaction
```

I should say this, the peace of code is part of big functionality. But this is the only transaction I'm using in that functionality. I have also written a couple of test scenarios for that functionality. This functionality works fine in the real world.

My doubt is more about the authorizing method since it's throwing an exception inside the transaction clouser. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does your test use any db traits like e.g. `DatabaseTransactions`?

Comment: Nope, I have written my own database-Inilitization trait. which it's run the migration once per the whole running tests process.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab did you figure out what was the problem? I still get this error once in a while

Comment: Nope @sobhan sorry. But i have figured out that sometimes it happens when other tests are failing, which it's not logical.

Comment: @mohammad.kaab as my tests are going on, I resolved the problem by limiting the number of tests in each file using `DatabaseTransactions`, and it solves the problem, maybe it's related to the number of connections in connection pool or the live time of them, I still digging, let you and the community know if found anything

Comment: This error can also appear if you are using `DatabaseTransactions` and any of your tests are using `Model::truncate()` to reset things.